# Rest Api call behaves unexpected from certain countries

Tags: c#, rest, http

There is a desktop application we use within the company. The application is written in C#. The coworkers who are using it are located in USA, Europa, China.

The desktop application connects to a server via web sockets (SignalR) and uses Rest Api calls. The server is also located in Europa.

The problem is; only when the coworkers from China uses this application, we get some errors from client application.

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a
> stream.  ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the
> transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by

AND

> Hub connection error System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The
> request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 120
> seconds elapsing.  ---> System.TimeoutException: The operation was
> canceled by the remote host

Using of HttpClient is pretty straight forward and working as expected in other projects.
Here is how we configure HttpClient

```
public class HttpConfiguration
{
    private HttpClient _client;       

    public HttpClient HttpClient => _client;

    public HttpConfiguration(string baseUrl)
    {
        _client = new HttpClient();
        _client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);
        _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));            
    }
 }
```

Here is how we make an example Api Call

```
public async Task<ApiResponse> SendMessage(MessageDto message)
{
    var connectionMessage = await _connectivityService.IsServerAliveAndInternetConnected();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionMessage))
    {
        _config.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ClearHeader().AddToken();
    
        var serialisedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
        var bodyContent = new StringContent(serialisedObject, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, ApiConstants.MEDIA_TYPE);
    
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _config.HttpClient.PostAsync(ApiConstants.SYNC_SEND_MESSAGE, bodyContent);
    
        return await ResponseFactory.GenerateResponse<SyncResponseModel>(response);
    }
    else
    {
        _config.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        return ResponseFactory.GenerateDirectMessageResponse(connectionMessage, false);
    }
}
```

I am aware that Europa to China is physically long distance and there might be some delays but the packages sent during api calls are pretty small. I set the timeout 3 minutes on purpose but still no use.

Could there be a way to solve this problem without setting up a gateway server?

Comment: It may be Great Chinese Firewall who did not like connections from inside China to the abroad services.

Comment: Xi Jingping Moment

Comment: @Serg I also tought of that. weird thing is, not all api calls are blocked like this but 20% of them.